# Using Class to instantiate my Song class

Tags: ruby, class, instantiation, class-variables

I'm going through the Learn Ruby the Hard Way - ex40

Currently, the code works fine. That is not my problem. My problem is every time I add a new song. A) I need to create an instance variable inside the initialize method. B) Then, I have to give it an attr_reader.

What I know if I can A) not have to keep creating new instance variable, but simply variables inside the Song class. B) Not have to create an attr_reader for each variable.

```
class Song
  def initialize()
    @jcole_lighter = "Come here, I\'m about to take you higher"
    @hold_on_drake = ["Cause you\'re a good girl and you know it",
                          "You act so different around me",
                          "Cause you\'re a good girl and you know it"]
  end


  def sing_me_a_song()
        for line in initialize
            puts line
        end
    end

  attr_reader :jcole_lighter
  attr_reader :hold_on_drake

end


thing = Song.new
puts thing.jcole_lighter()
puts "-"*10
thing= Song.new
puts thing.hold_on_drake()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) out for a good explanation of `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, and `attr_accessor`.

And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214049/is-it-acceptable-having-parameter-in-class-constructor/3214293#3214293) out for learning how to add parameters to the constructor.

You could have `:attr_accessor :artists` inside `Song` and in `initialize` do this:

```
@artists = Array.new
```

Then you can have a method `add`:

```
def add(artist)
  @artists << artist
end
```

Just an idea. Always happy to help a Drake fan.

Comment: I didn't necessary use the << to artist but used a if-else statement to get lyrics of an artist's if called.