# mongoid criteria result doesn't fill all field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am new to Rails and MongoDB as well as MongoID..

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :fbid, type: String
  field :facebookname, type: String
  field :competitorFbid, type: String
  field :createdAt, type: DateTime
  field :updatedAt, type: DateTime

  # building constructor the rails way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3214293/474330
  def initialize(options = {})
    @fbid = options[:fbid]
    @facebookname = options[:facebookname]
    @competitorFbid = options[:competitorFbid]
  end

  def writeasjson
    hash = { :fbid => @fbid, 
      :facebookname => @facebookname, 
      :competitorFbid => @competitorFbid, 
      :createdAt => @createdAt,
      :updatedAt => @updatedAt
    }
    hash.to_json
  end

  attr_accessor :fbid, :facebookname, :competitorFbid, :createdAt, :updatedAt
end
```

I am using MongoID to query my mongodb database like this:

```
myuser = User.where(fbid: params[:fbid]).first
render :json => myuser.writesajson
```

However, the result is all the fields are "null"

If I print the criteria result like this,

```
render :json => myuser
```

it prints all the `_id`, `authData` and `bcryptPassword` field, however the rest of the field have `null` value,

Here is what I got from the MongoDB database in my app. If I query from MongoHub, all the null values will be filled

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56d2872f00af597fa584e367"
    },
    "authData": {
        "facebook": {
            "access_token": "yEf8cZCs9uTkrOq0ZCHJJtgPFxPAig9yhW6DhBCLuJqPdMZBLPu",
            "expiration_date": "2016-04-17T13:52:12.000Z",
            "id": "9192631770"
        }
    },
    "bcryptPassword": "$2a$10$9mUW3JWI51GxM1VilA",
    "competitorFbid": null,
    "createdAt": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "facebookname": null,
    "fbid": null,
    "objectId": "nLurZcAfBe",
    "runCount": 2446,
    "sessionToken": "0SwPDVDu",
    "updatedAt": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "XgcWo4iUCK"
}
```

I have been debugging the whole day without any light, any help will be greatly appreciated...

EDIT:
adding the response

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"56d2872f00af597fa584e366"},"authData":{"facebook":{"access_token":"[ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED]","expiration_date":"2015-12-19T14:17:25.000Z","id":"[ID_REMOVED]"}},"bcryptPassword":"[PASSWORD_REMOVED]","competitorFbid":null,"createdAt":null,"created_at":null,"facebookname":null,"fbid":null,"objectId":"H5cEMtUzMo","runCount":790,"sessionToken":"[SESSION_TOKEN_REMOVED]","updatedAt":null,"updated_at":null,"username":"[USERNAME_REMOVED]"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field in the database is declared using the `field` method:

```
field :fbid, type: String
```

This also defines `fbid` and `fbid=` methods to work with the `fbid` *attribute*.

An instance variable with associated accessor and mutator methods is declared using the [`attr_accessor`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) method:

```
attr_accessor :fbid
```

This will also add `fbid` and `fbid=` methods to work with the underlying *instance variable*.

They're not the same thing. Mongoid only knows about `field`s, those are the things that it will work with in the database so your query works; `field` also defines accessor and mutator methods for your fields.

But you have an `attr_accessor` call *after* your `field` calls so the methods that `field` creates (such as `fbid` and `fbid=`) are overwritten by those created by `attr_accessor`. The result is that all your attributes appear to be `nil`.

The solution is to drop the `attr_accessor` call from your class. You only need the `field` calls.

Comment: I know this is an old question. Is there any documentation on how to deal with this particular ambivalence? In complex queries it is difficult to know when you should switch from the lazy approach of MongoDB to the ruby/rails search (`#to_a`, `#all`, `#select`). It seems really tricky to figure out a way that offers the best performance cut (there's seems to be nothing generic to aim for and at the same time prevent redundant information to get to your MongoDB model)

Comment: @rellampec Sorry, I haven't touched MongoDB in years, partly because it became so cumbersome to work with.