# Immutable objects in ruby

Tags: ruby, immutability

Can anyone list out the immutable objects in Ruby..

I saw [Ruby - Immutable Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408208/ruby-immutable-objects) this and I know about how to convert mutable objects into immutable objects but no clarity on immutable objects in ruby.

Comment: Why Down vote..?  give a reason or sources.

Comment: Yes give a reason before you down vote

Comment: What does "list out the mutable objects in Ruby" mean?

Comment: @Chuck I mean the datatypes/objects like strings ,arrays,hashes etc.

Comment: I don't want to be a downer, but listing every class in the Ruby standard library is way outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @Chuck  Please find the edit in my question. And let me know whether in your view all the objects in ruby are immutable objects or not.

Comment: Presumably you mean "list out the Classes where all instances are created immutable"? For example: `Fixnum.frozen? # false` versus `5.frozen? # true`? Otherwise I could start my list of objects, `0`, `1`, `2` . . .  if I answered your question literally . ..

Comment: With all my respect, but this is a very interesting question whose scope deserves to be discussed in this forum. I think it was a mistake to have closed it

Answer (score 4):

It's been my experience that you have two choices:

- Aggressively `freeze` any objects, and this means *deep freeze* where you not only freeze the main object but any contained objects, in order to prevent modification.
- Be disciplined about not modifying the objects in certain sections of your code.

The second approach is what most applications use because once frozen there's no way to un-freeze something. Objective-C has mutable and non-mutable variants of many objects, C++ has `const` that can prevent modification of any object, but there's no such thing in Ruby.

This is largely because Ruby methods are free to do whatever they want with very little in the way of constraints. Can a reader method modify the state of the object? Yes. You might have a very good reason for doing this and Ruby won't get in your way.

If you're writing code that depends on objects being in a non-changing state, make a copy, freeze it, and use that for reference. This will probably slow down and complicate your application considerably, so it's a very heavy handed approach.

The best method is to share as little information as is necessary, provide interfaces to this information that are read-only by design, and avoid tampering with things outside of specific circumstances by employing proper locking measures.

Comment: So you mean every object is mutable in ruby. If we want to make it immutable we have to freeze it right ?

Comment: @pramod: A few Ruby core classes create instances that are already frozen - enforced in the interpreter (and this varies depending on Ruby version you are using). E.g. Float: `(2.3).frozen? # true`